# How to access the parent index id in an Object array in Angular?

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I am creating a dynamic table row with an input fields. In angular we can access the index of array by using this `$index` variable. Now my problem is I have a sublevels array and I need to get the index of the parent array.
And every row has a remove button. And I need to access the parent index ID for accessing.

Here's the sample object value:

```
Object
    items: Array [2]
        0: Object
            particular_name: "SAMPLE PARTICULAR TITLE"
            child_label: Object
            items: Array [3]
                0: Object
                1: Object
                2: Object
            $$hashKey: "object:13"
        1: Object
            particular_name: "SAMPLE PARTICULAR TITLE"
            child_label: Object
            items: Array [0]
            $$hashKey: "object:41"
```

In my template I have this:

```
<!-- this is the parent array -->
<div ng-repeat="item in quoteHeader.items" class="row">
    <!-- some codes here... -->
    <!-- 2nd level array -->
    <tr ng-repeat="item in quoteHeader.items[$index].child_label.items">
    <!-- need to access the parent index ID here... But index ID here is the index of the 2nd level array-->
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeParent($index)"><span class="fa fa-times"></span></button>
```

JS:

```
 $scope.removeParent = function($index) {   
        console.log($index);
        //$scope.quoteHeader.items[$index].splice($index, 1);           
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `ng-repeat` creates a child scope with the passed data. You need to get the parent index in child data by using `$parent`. Like

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeParent($parent.$index)"><span class="fa fa-times"></span></button>
```

Another way to use `ng-init` directive. Just see an example

```
<div ng-repeat="item in quoteHeader.items" class="row" ng-init="parentIndex = $index">
    <!-- some codes here... -->
    <!-- 2nd level array -->
    <tr ng-repeat="item in quoteHeader.items[$index].child_label.items">
    <!-- need to access the parent index ID here... But index ID here is the index of the 2nd level array-->
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeParent(parentIndex)"><span class="fa fa-times"></span></button>
```

Comment: Is it applicable in multiple sublevels?

Comment: Yes. in that case you need to call `removeParent($parent.$parent.$index)` to the depth of your object or array.